# What are the on-rate and off-rate constants for 5-HT1 receptors binding 5-HT?

Tags: neurotransmitter, kinetics

The class of 5-HT<sub>1</sub> receptors binds serotonin (5-HT) reversibly ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-HT1A_receptor)). I'm interested in the on-rate and off-rate constants $k_{\text{on}}$ and $k_{\text{off}}$ of this process.

So my question is: Have these constants already been determined experimentally for any member of the 5-HT<sub>1</sub> receptor family, and, if so, what where the values observed?

---

**Edit**: Since this question didn't get much attention yet: Instead of the on-rate and off-rate, maybe the dissociaton constant/binding constant of the binding process is known?